# How do i find element in website that constanly change its label ID deep inside nested DIV?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I have a site that tracking all our shipment and i would like to use Selenium with Python to fetch all the value into my Excel file. But i'm currently stuck at getting Selenium to work. It will keep reporting back to me that the element is nowhere to be found. The element are also deep deep in the nested of DIV stuff.

[image: Tons of nested, don't know where to start.]

at first i tried using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='trackItNowForm:j_idt529:0:j_idt535']").text
```

And quickly found out that part of the ID will constantly changing. (the "idt529:0:j_idt535" part in ID will constantly change to 519, 509 and so on. The zero path will also change based on lenght of data.) Without a clear structure. With that, By.ID is also obviously out of the window.

So now i'm currently out of idea on what to do next. Maybe i didn't put in the corrected syntax? I'm new to Selenium so i'm still confuse on a lot of things (like how XPATH are written and so on.) So an explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! You just can use different selectors, like CSS_SELECTOR, the code might look like this : 
`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.ui-outputlabel.ui-widget.TrackingNumber").text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate that element by it's `TrackingNumber` class name. Maybe combined with more known attributes values.
Please try this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[contains(@id,'trackItNowForm') and(contains(@class,'TrackingNumber'))]").text
```

You may probably will need to add a delay to wait for the element to be visible. In this case `WebDriverWait` expected conditions is the right way to do it, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(@id,'trackItNowForm') and(contains(@class,'TrackingNumber'))]"))).text
```

Comment: I mix your WebDriverWait code and @KunduK CSS Selector and was also to solve all the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm happy my answer was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following css selector to identify the element.

option 1:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='trackItNowForm'][id*='id']").text
```

option 2:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='trackItNowForm'][id*='id'][class*='TrackingNumber']").text
```

where `^` means starts-with and `*` contains.

In option 1, it is checking `id` attribute starts-with `trackItNowForm` and also contains `id`

Comment: Wait so i can write CSS Selector like a Regex? That's definitely new to me. Thank you for the answer. Though unfortunately i can only picked one answer so i decided to go with @Prophet's answer (as he also offer a solution for a potential issue that i might come up later.) I'll upvoted your answer regardless. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how xpath works.
For example, for the code you provided:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='col-sm-10']/label").text`
looks for the first occurrence of a *label* under a *div* with the attribute `class='col-sm-10'` and then takes its *text*.

Useful links:

- [XPath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)